# UserDefinedAggregateFunction merge() buffer always unpopulated

Tags: scala, apache-spark, user-defined-functions

I'm trying to create my own spark scala UserDefinedAggregateFunction for a simple stock analysis program, but I'm having trouble with the merge function.  When I print the contents of the buffer after populating them in the update method the values appear to have been populated. Unfortunately the buffer parameter of the merge function doesn't have any meaningful values.  The data appears as though it has just been initialized.

The debug output prints the following line multiple times:

```
DEBUG:  AggregateDeltaVolume.merge buffer(0)=0 buffer(1)=0.0
```

There are no cases where the buffer parameter of the merge function contains populated fields other than default values.

```
import java.time._
import java.time.LocalDateTime
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter

import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.MutableAggregationBuffer
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._

class AggregateDeltaVolume extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction {
  override def inputSchema: org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(
      Array(StructField("min", DoubleType), StructField("max", DoubleType))
  )

  override def bufferSchema: StructType = StructType(
    StructField("count", LongType) ::
    StructField("volumeDeltaSum", DoubleType) :: Nil
  )

  override def dataType: DataType = DoubleType

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = 0L
    buffer(1) = 0.0d
  }

  // Updates the given aggregation buffer buffer with new input data from input.
  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val min:Double = input.getAs[Double](0)
    val max:Double = input.getAs[Double](1)
    val delta:Double = (max - min) / min
    buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[Long](0) + 1L
    buffer(1) = buffer.getAs[Double](1) + delta 
  }

  // Merges two aggregation buffers and stores the updated buffer values back to buffer1.
  override def merge(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    println("DEBUG:  AggregateDeltaVolume.merge buffer(0)=" + buffer(0) + " buffer(1)=" + buffer(1))
    buffer(0) = buffer.getAs[Long](0) + input.getAs[Long](0)
    buffer(1) = buffer.getAs[Double](1) + input.getAs[Double](1)
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    buffer.getDouble(1) / buffer.getLong(0)
  }

  override def deterministic: Boolean = true
}

val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)

val adv = new AggregateDeltaVolume
sqlContext.udf.register("adv", adv)
spark.udf.register("adv", adv)

val df = spark.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").load("./data/2018-02-01/2018-02-01_BINS_XETR08.csv")

val dayView = df.groupBy("Mnemonic", "Date").agg(expr("adv(MinPrice, MaxPrice) as AvgDeltaVolume"))
dayView.show
```

Comment: That's odd - your code seems to work well for me. Getting printouts like `DEBUG:  AggregateDeltaVolume.merge buffer(0)=6 buffer(1)=54.0`. I'm using Spark 2.1.1 and Scala 2.11, in case it helps narrow this down.

Comment: I'm using version Spark 2.3.0 and Scala version 2.11.12

Comment: Just tested with Spark 2.3.0 - still works for me... not sure what may have gone wrong on your side. I'd try to run this in simple, small, hard-coded input data, to see what's going on - perhaps there's something specifically odd / wrong with the CSV you're loading or how you're loading it.

Comment: Ok, so I was able to run it against a smaller CSV.  I saw similar empty buffers, but the result came back with correct values.  I'm wondering if it has something to do with the way the data is organized or possibly there's something preventing it from running in parallel.